# Java calling function with class in argument

Tags: java, oop

We have simple homework. I need to create a user with address in java. But I can't figure out where to write address or how to connect the address to user.

My User

```
package xxx;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class User {

    private String ID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int idNumber;
    private String email;
    private Address officialAddress;
    private Address postAddress;
    private List contracts;



    public User(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber, String email,Address officialAddress, Address postAddress) {
        ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setIdNumber(idNumber);
        setEmail(email);
    }


    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        if(firstName == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill firstName");
        } this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        if(lastName == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill lastName");
        } this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(int idNumber) {
        if(idNumber > 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill idNumber");
        } this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public int getIdNumber(){
        return idNumber;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        if(email == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill email");
        } this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

}
```

My address

```
package xxx;

public class Address {

    private int zipcode;
    private String region;
    private String streetName;
    private int streetNumber;

    public Address(int zipcode, String region, String streetName, int streetNumber) {
        setZipcode(zipcode);
        setRegion(region);
        setStreetName(streetName);
        setStreetNumber(streetNumber);

    }

    private void setZipcode(int zipcode) {
        if(zipcode > 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill zipcode");
        } this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    private int getZipcode(){
        return zipcode;
    }

    private void setRegion(String region) {
        if(region == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill region");
        } this.region = region;
    }

    private String getRegion(){
        return region;
    }

    private void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        if(streetName == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill region");
        } this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    private String getStreetName(){
        return streetName;
    }

    private void setStreetNumber(int streetNumber) {
        if(streetNumber > 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill zipcode");
        } this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
    }

    private int getStreetNumber(){
        return streetNumber;
    }
}
```

But how i can create user if there is no address in arguments. But i dont know how to create it with that address argument.(Maybe i need it to put out of arguments and connect somehow different).

And this is my try but i get error that i need to fill zipcode.

```
private Scanner scannerBuff = new Scanner(System.in);
private String firstName;
private User customer;
private Address officialAddress;
private Address postAddress;

public Engine() {

    officialAddress = new Address(484984,"gdfgfd","gdfgdfgdf",4);
    postAddress = new Address(484984,"gdfgdf","gdfgdfg",4);
    customer = new User("gdfgdf","gdfgdf",123456,"fdsfd",officialAddress,postAddress );
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't do the getter/setter like the others for both Adress in User class ? If officialAddress and postAddress are attributs of User, I think you shouldn't make them attribut of Engine

Comment: @azro I am sorry but I don't understand how it is meant.

Comment: What is the problem ? Connect the addresses to the user the same way you connect the name, ID, number, ... into the User constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle addresses, or no addresses, make multiple constructors

```
public User(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber, String email) {
    ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    setFirstName(firstName);
    setLastName(lastName);
    setIdNumber(idNumber);
    setEmail(email);
}


public User(String firstName, String lastName, int idNumber, String email, Address officialAddress, Address postAddress) {
    this(firstName, lastName, idNumber, email); // call the first constructor to avoid duplicate code
    setOfficialAdress(officialAddress);
    setPostAdress(postAddress);
}
```

And the setters like the others

```
public void setOfficialAdress(Address officialAddress) {
    if(officialAddress == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill officialAddress");
    } 
    this.officialAddress = officialAddress;
}
```

Comment: @JurajJakubov I've just edit the 2nd constructor so it calls the first one to avoid code duplication